# How do I create a shipment via REST API magento2?

Tags: magento2, rest-api, shipment, multi-source-inventory, msi

Can someone help me about the shipment. How can I pass the MSI source code to the Shipment Create API?

Thanks

Comment: provide us the endpoint and payload you are using

Comment: /V1/order/{orderId}/ship

Comment: please edit your question with the payload you are using

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this through rest API /V1/order/{orderId}/ship
I did this by adding the source code into the API.

```
{
  "items": [
    {
      "extension_attributes": {},
      "order_item_id": 1482,
      "qty": 1
    }
  ],
  "notify": false,
  "appendComment": true,
  "comment": {
    "extension_attributes": {},
    "comment": "Shipment Create",
    "is_visible_on_front": 0
  },
  "tracks": [
    {
      "extension_attributes": {},
      "track_number": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
      "title": "Custom",
      "carrier_code": "custom"
    }
  ],
  "arguments": {
    "extension_attributes": {
      "source_code": "source_code"
    }
  }
}
```

Thanks